# MySQL JOIN Not unique table/alias:

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT punkty_skupu.id, punkty_skupu.nazwa_punktu, punkty_skupu.miejscowosc, trasy.czas_przejazdu_tekst
FROM punkty_skupu LEFT JOIN
     punkty_skupu
     ON trasy.id_punktu = punkty_skupu.id
```

Comment: I formatted the SQL, but do you have a question ?

Answer (score 0):

Presumably, you are getting an error message because you have an undefined table alias:

```
SELECT punkty_skupu.id, punkty_skupu.nazwa_punktu, punkty_skupu.miejscowosc, 
       trasy.czas_przejazdu_tekst
FROM punkty_skupu LEFT JOIN
     punkty_skupu trasy
------------------^
     ON trasy.id_punktu = punkty_skupu.id
```